# Changing icon in chrome packaged app in status bar

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is it possible to update icon in runtime in chrome packaged app? 
I was searching for a long time, but could not find anything (outside changing the icon for chrome extension using browserAction.setIcon or pageAction.setIcon).

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't.

Chrome Platform is not mature at all.